# How to hide a template in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to hide a template file in admin?

For example I have a template that should only be available if a specific plugin is installed, and I already know how to check if plugin is active. But how do I hide the template?

For example I want to hide "Blogger Redirection"-template bellow:

[image: Image is just an example...]

I have found several links, but all of the solutions seems deprecated.

**EDIT:** *If anyone is interested in how I check if pluin is active I do it with the following function:*

```
function isPluginActive($plugin){
        if ( in_array( $plugin, apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Read [this](http://foliovision.com/seo-tools/wordpress/how-to/hack-wordpress-theme/identify-template-file) wonderful article, maybe you will find answer there.

Comment: No, didn't really help. Nothing about hiding a template in that article. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Are you saying you want the admin not to see the template listed if he doesn't have the correct plugin?

Comment: @MrGlass YES! Exactly. If a plugin isn't installed and that template requires it. Let's say if I have a template that uses Advanced Custom Fields plugin, and it isn't installed then that template file shouldn't be an option.

Comment: I dont think thats possible. You would need to have wordpress run your code (to hide the template) without your code being selected (since the concept here is that they can't use the template).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update - a word of caution as pointed out by andrew in the comments below:**

> Use this code with caution, If you have any pages using the template that you removed from the select, updating the page will cause it to revert to the default template

---

I'm not sure if there is a PHP way of doing this - you'll have to look in the `WP_Theme` class, but from my first look it might not be possible because in order to get all templates, the class utilizes an internal function called [`scandir()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php#L965) which scans the current theme directory and gets all `.php` files from there. It then looks for the corresponding `Template Name:` identifier and if it's present it gets added to the templates list.

So instead I suggest, that you add a little JS that will remove this option from the page template select. Here's a code snippet:

```
function my_remove_page_template() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post-new.php', 'post.php') ) && get_post_type() == 'page' ) { ?>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#page_template option[value="sidebar-page.php"]').remove();
                })
            })(jQuery)
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_remove_page_template', 10);
```

This will remove the template `sidebar-page.php` from the dropdown. The conditionals are so that the script is only added on add and edit screens of pages.

Adjust to your case and enjoy :)

Comment: +1 for making sure that the script is included only add and edit screens.

Comment: +1 for explaining how WP checks for template files.

Comment: Use this code with caution, If you have any pages using the template that you removed from the select, updating the page will cause it to revert to the default template

Comment: This is a great solution for sites using the Classic Editor. Any idea on how to accomplish similar when using the Gutenberg Block Editor? 
Not only are the select IDs much harder to grab, it doesn't appear like the select box even exists on page load (and only gets created when someone opens that panel)

Answer (score 4):

WordPress doesn't provide any hook, so you can't remove it from PHP.

One alternative that I could think of is that you can remove it dynamically using JavaScript. Include a snippet of JavaScript in the `add post` page which will remove the option from the `select` element.

I know this is not a clean solution, but I think this is the only possible way as of now.

**Edit**:

Another option is to copy the template file to the theme directory when the Plugin is activated and remove the template file when the Plugin is deactivated.

This assumes that the template is used only by this Plugin.

Comment: I agree, for now this may be the only option.

Comment: I see. I feared this was the case. Guess a js hack will have to do the work. ;)

Comment: You can also try out the second option that I posted in my answer.

Comment: You could probably add your own `register_activation_hook()` or hook to the [activate_(plugin_file_name)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/activate_(plugin_file_name)) action hook, where you will insert the appropriate PHP comments that define a file as a Page template and on plugin deactivation you can remove them.