# Not showing a page template if one already is published

Tags: wordpress

My scenario is simple.
I have a page template and if one page is saved under that custom page template type, it should not be available in the admin page template drop-down-box. Anybody know of a way to do this fast and easy? I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. I've done some research and I don't believe there is a function that would allow for this to be done. I'd be glad to be proven wrong, but I can't see anyway for this to occur.

Comment: the solution I can think of would be to go trough all the pages and check for each if it is that custom page template type. If it is, it exits the loop. Or a custom query in the wp_posts table for that custom page template type. But I'm looking for a better way... Hope someone has an idea for it...

Comment: Well that would work, but it wouldn't make it disappear as a option in the Page Template dropdown.

Comment: there is a way to include the custom page template programatically http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13378/add-custom-template-page-programmatically so if I check and it exists, you don't include it

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. I'd say that is your best bet in getting it in there only once.

Comment: hmm, setting an option on creation might be a hack idea to check for availability of the page...

Comment: umm how about iterating across the page_meta to check if the template is in there somewhere. and if it is remove it from the drop down..
get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ); ?

Comment: @vimes1984 that's an idea worth trying... thanks!

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/checking-for-the-existence-of-an-active-page-template should start you of in the rightdirection..

Comment: if you find a answer post it I'll vote it up

Comment: Put it in a answer... maybe not the best way to go about it but it's the only way i can think of...

Answer (score 1):

Ok as suggested by the user here goes: 
why not loop through the

`get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) );`

to check if the page template is in the page's meta values and if it is remove it from the drop down.. 
something like this:

[How to hide a template in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566676/how-to-hide-a-template-in-wordpress)

Should hide the template and something like this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/checking-for-the-existence-of-an-active-page-template

Will allow you to check the page template to see  if it's being used...